# Where to put the SFML 2.3.2 templates for Xcode 7.3?

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode7, sfml

I followed the [tutorial for installing SFML for Xcode](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-osx.php). It says:

> "Copy the SFML directory from templates to
>   /Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates (create the folders if they don't
>   exist yet)."

I tried that and it didn't work (the templates did not show up in Xcode).

Versions:

```
SFML 2.3.2
Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11.4
Xcode 7.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was using that directory relative to my home directory (`~`):

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates
cp -pr templates/* ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates
```